Button only working around the button and not on the actual button
My Add assignment button only works when I click the red around and not the button that I created.
I'm new and was wondering how to fix this.Photo of issue
ZStack {
    Spacer()
    Button(action: {
        withAnimation {
            assignments.append(AssignmentRow())
        }
    }) {
        HStack {
            Image(systemName: "plus.circle.fill")
            Text("Add Assignment")
        }
        .font(.footnote) // Adjust font size here
        .padding(10) // Adjust padding here
        .foregroundColor(.white)
        .background(isPressed ? Color.blue.opacity(0.7) : Color.blue)
        .cornerRadius(10) // Add rounded corners
        .scaleEffect(isPressed ? 0.95 : 1.0) // Scale effect when pressed
        .shadow(color: isPressed ? Color.gray : Color.clear, radius: 10, x: 0, y: 10) // Shadow effect
        .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.2), value: isPressed) // Animation for the effect
    }
    .frame(width: 150, height: 40) // Set fixed frame for the button
    .onLongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 0.1, pressing: { pressing in
        isPressed = pressing
    }) {
        // Action is already handled in the button action closure
    }
    Spacer()
}
.listRowBackground(Color.red) // Set row background to white to remove grey
.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center) // Center align the frame


I set the background to red to show what area I click.
I've tried to set the frame to be the same size as a button and it still dosen't work also multiple other things.

Show a minimal reproducible code that produces your issue, see: minimal code.
Show the code surrounding the ZStack, is it in a List, or in a Menu etc...

Note that you don't need a language tag in your title; it's a tag

Try using a ButtonStyle to apply the styling. See the answer to How to resize a button foreground to fit its view in a SwiftUI form for an example.

Maybe the spacer is blocking the button. Try removing the Spacer() elements, the button should be positioned correctly within the ZStack. This should resolve the issue of the button not being clickable in the intended area. If the button is still not centered as desired, you can try wrapping the button in a VStack or HStack with Spacer() elements to center it

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Try putting .onLongPressGesture on the image.
For example,
struct ContentView: View {
  @State private var scale: CGFloat = 1.0
  var body: some View {
    Image(systemName: "plus.circle.fill")
    Text("Add Assignment")
        .scaleEffect(scale)
        .gesture(
            LongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 1)
                .onEnded { _ in
                    scale /= 2
                }
        )
}


I just added a custom buttonstyle and it's working perfectly now.
Thanks everyone who replied!
